# Python configparser get all from a section and write to new file

Tags: python, parsing, config, python-config

how would one use python config parser to get every entry under a single section and write to a new file without actually specifying each entry

for example how would I go about getting everything under section "testing" and write to a new file without using config.get and listing every entry?

config file

```
[testing]
test1=test23452
test2=test45235
test3=test54524
[donotneed]
something1=something
something2=somethingelse
```

I've tried the following just for testing purposes

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(configFilePath)
    testing = {k:v for k,v in config.items('testing')}
    for x in testing:
        print (x)
```

but it's only printing the following

```
test1
test3
test2
```

and not everything in that section, I need it to give me

```
test1=test23452
test2=test45235
test3=test54524
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for x in testing` will just parse the keys of the dictionary `testing`.

You need:

```py
for x in testing.items():
  print x[0] + '=' + x[1]
```